# Master/Slave implementation and load balancing on SOAP services with Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, master-slave

There are 2 web services **A** and **B** to communicate with each other and external system.

**Information**

- **A** consumes many different data from external system periodically. *(each data separately)*
- Also, clients send some data to **A**.
- **A** is sending the data to **B**.
- Communication is over the **SOAP** according to wsdl.
- Written in **Spring Boot/Java**.

**What I tried**

- Implemented micro services structure basically for load balancing such as Registry Service (**Netflix Eureka**) and API Gateway (**Netflix Zool**).
- Integrated **A** service with registry service.
- Created 2 **A** service for load balancing.
- Tried some examples on it.

**At this point;**

- How can I set up a Master/Slave for **A** and **B** services?
- How can avoid the consuming request from **A** over multiple instances?
  *Every **A** service will request for consuming separately*
- In these scenarios, Every incoming request passing through **Zuul** then **A** instances. What about the outgoing requests on A over multiple instances? Should we pass the outgoing requests over Zuul or similar?
- How can I set up a Zuul or similar implementation on **B** service?

Thank you for now.

Comment: Did you find sth?